# Fetch attribute values from GFF3 database wiith bioperl

Tags: bioperl

I already created a  GFF3 DB with BioPerl  Store Object (BIO:DB:SeqFeature:Store)
I created the GFF3 file by myself from a Blastx result and created a series of my own tags as attributes. Now I would fetch this values from the database that BioPerl creates for me....

how can I do it?

Please help! 
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found that exist functions to do this in the package `BIO::SeqFeature::Generic`.
The most useful is `get_tag_values` that returns an array with each value contained in the attributes with a specific tag given in input!

Usage:

```
my @values= $feature->get_tag_values('go');
```

Bye all!